# Not able to install any DB2 LUW 10.5 fixpacks

Tags: db2, upgrade, errors, db2-10.5

I am currently on Fixpack 1 and am trying to install ANY more recent fixpack. All of them refuse to apply themselves with similar errors. The one below is from Fixpack 2 file `v10.5fp2_ntx64_server`. Each of them up to the most recent says that they cannot upgrade my version, but none of them provides a reason.

[image]

After reading [Installation Planning link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/r0006867.html), my brain hurts after coming across of this:

> DB2 must be installed on a drive with short names enabled or a directory with no spaces such as E:\DB2\SQLLIB. To check the current 8.3 file name settings for a drive, in a command window with administrator privileges, enter

```
fsutil.exe behavior query disable8dot3
```

> The following possible values are returned when you run the command:

```
0: Create 8.3 short file names (default)
1: Do not create 8.3 file names
2: Set 8.3 file names on a per volume basis
3: Disable 8.3 file names on all volumes, except the system volume
```

> The registry state of NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation is 0, which means that 8.3 file names are enabled on all volumes. To enable 8.3 file names on a global basis, enter

```
fsutil.exe behavior set disable8dot3 0
```

> If DB2 is installed on a drive without 8.3 name support andin a directory without spaces, it must be reinstalled on a drive with 8.3 name support. If the folder you are trying to install DB2 is already created when 8.3 name support is disabled, then the short name is not created if you try a reinstall onto the same directory. Windows short names are created during the directory creation, hence you must install it into a new directory or if the directory is empty delete the directory and allow recreation.

On my system, the setting is at its default 2, which means "per volume". I am not sure if this is the reason the fixpacks refuse to install themselves.

Does this mean that IBM essentially puts their customers into a death trap, by allowing the initial install of DB2 to place it into `C:\Program Files\` but refusing to install fixpacks later? I cannot believe that this is the case. Can anyone whose DB2 runs off of `C:\Program Files\` explain how we are supposed to upgrade?

UPDATE:

By running `dir /x` I found out that all directories in the hierarchy from `c:\` down to `sqllib` have short names. The lack of them cannot be the reason why updates are refusing to install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your screenshot this is Express-**C** edition. It cannot be upgraded with fixpack.
See [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1311whichdb2edition/index.html#figure-expressc-vs-express)
[image]

In my opinion your best bet is to leave it as is or plan for migration to newer version. IBM provides only newest Express-C edition from what I could gather.

Comment: Such a small difference for IBM, but such a huge difference for a customer :( I guess, spelling it out clearly was absolutely impossible for IBM, and they enjoyed me wasting several hours for this investigation.

Answer (score 0):

An [idea for the customer](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/db2),
the current version from December 1, 2020 - is DB2 11.5.5.0

Comment: my hint for the customer was - trying docker with db2 LUW - with this offer from IBM there is no need dealing with fixpacks   --- PS as a newbie in this forum maybe the link posted first was no ok.....

Comment: Thanks for the thought but we are not interested in using docker.

Answer (score -1):

asking google - I found at kbce.com:
Looking for Db2 Express-C Edition? That product does no longer exist and is replaced by Db2 Community Edition!
IBM Db2 Community Edition 11.5, RAM: 16GB, CPU: 4 sockets or 4 cores, Database size: 100GB! No further restrictions or disabled features!